# excel - holiday costs, sum up who paid for what

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

A friend and I visit a new place each month. We log our costs in an excel doc. The doc looks like this:

[image]

I want to sum up the costs paid for by "M" and "L".

I'm not sure why but my formula doesn't work properly even though I think its correct. I use a combination of sumif, index and match to do this. See forumla in image.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over-complicating it, it's simply:

```
(B14=)    =SUMIF($C$1:$C$12,A14,$B$1:$B$12)
```

copy/paste at `B15`.

And be more generous with your girlfriend :/

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:
`=SUMIF($C$2:$C$12,A14,$B$2:$B$12)`

Sumif can use Criteria Range where you have M and L in your Data
A14 the Criteria
Sum Range where you have the numbers to Sum
It will check for the Rows in C2:C13 = "M" for example and return the Value in the corresponding rows in B2:B12
$ for absolute references so you can drag the formula

For more information click [Sumif](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation yass but I had to give it to ASH as he/she was first. But upvoted.

Comment: Do not include C13 and B13 in it like your example

Comment: For the detailed explanation +1 :)